# VBA to copy and paste transpose within different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have 200 different workbook. I want to copy and paste transpose from 1 sheet into another worksheet. Is there a VBA code for that?

For example: 
Workbook 1 now has 1 worksheet called worksheet A.

I want to copy, paste transpose worksheet A into worksheet 1, within workbook 1.

Is there a code that works for workbook 1-200?

```
Sub Macro2() 
    Dim thiswb As Workbook, datawb As Workbook 
    Dim datafolder As String 
    Dim cell As Range, datawblist As Range 
    Dim i As Integer 

    Set thiswb = ActiveWorkbook 
    i = 2 'Have the 40 file names in sheet2 of this workbook in cells A1:A40 
    Set datawblist = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:A40") 
    Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Select 
    datafolder = "H:\TestData\" 'change this to your directory they're in 

    For Each cell In datawblist 
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=datafolder & cell & ".xlsx", ReadOnly:=True 
        Set datawb = ActiveWorkbook
        Sheets("sheet1").Select 'change this to the sheet name you need to copy from 
        Range("C3").Select 

        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "" 
            Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(38, ActiveCell.Column)).Copy 
            thiswb.Activate
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select 'change if not sheet1 
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _ 
                                   Operation:=xlNone, _
                                   SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                   Transpose:=True 
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 36).Select 
            datawb.Activate 
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select 
        Loop 

        datawb.Close savechanges:=False 
        thiswb.Activate
        Sheets("sheet1").Select 
        i = i + 1
        Cells(i, 1).Select 
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes there is, if you write that code yourself. This is not a free coding service so you will need to show (the code) what you already have tried and ask a specific question to that code, otherwise the question is off-topic (see [ask]).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: I know there is one to copy and paste from different files into 1. How may I edit this?

Comment: @BryanLwy Please format your code nicely and indent each line correctly otherwise it is unreadable. Without the linebreaks it won't even compile. Format it exactly the same way you have it in your VBA editor and indent each line at least 4 spaces. Also tell if you get any errors if yes which and where. Which part is not working? What is already working? Where did you get stuck?